# Optional Property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is possible in neo4j to set a property of a node or a relationship in neo4j as mandatory or optional? If so, how to do it using cypher or RESTGraphDb interface provide by neo4j? Any help will be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Neo4j is schemaless, so all properties are optional for nodes as for relationships.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen: thanks for the reply. I know that Neo4J is schemaless database. But is it possible to set a flag for a property as mandatory?

Comment: You can just add more properties in different nodes For eg.
CREATE (person1 { personId: 1})
CREATE (person2 { personId: 2, Flag: True })
or you should add more details to your questions. People will be able to help you out more :)

Comment: No currently you can not have mandatory properties. Well it will be possible in next neo4j version 2.3-RC1

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen could you please let me know when do expect it to be released and where can I find information on the syntax and documentation on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j is schemaless and you are not able to have mandatory properties on a node or a relationship, at least not out-of-the-box.

This functionality will be available in Neo4j **Enterprise** 2.3+

But you can create that functionality by your own. You can create Unmanaged Extension which will use Transaction Event API or you can use GraphAware Framework for that.

Here are resources about that
- [Neo4j Improved Transaction Event API](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html)

Or you can wait for [GraphAware Enterprise](http://graphaware.com/enterprise/) which will be released later year and will have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `NOT NULL` constraint on a node -

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS NOT NULL
```